# How parent widget know it should move the childs when child be smaller or bigger?

Tags: flutter

```
class ColorStatefulBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorStatefulBox({Key? key, required this.color}) : super(key: key);
  final Color color;

  @override
  State<ColorStatefulBox> createState() => _ColorBoxState();
}


class _ColorBoxState extends State<ColorStatefulBox> {
  int count = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        count++;
        setState(() {});
      },
      child: Container(
        color: widget.color,
        width: 100+count.toDouble(),
        height: 100+count.toDouble(),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            count.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  List<Widget> widgetList = [
    ColorStatefulBox(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      key: GlobalKey(),
    ),
    ColorStatefulBox(
      color: Colors.blue,
      key: GlobalKey(),
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("key test"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
              children: [...widgetList],),
        ),);
  }
}
```

when click ColorStatefulBox, it will be bigger.And the other one ColorStatefulBox will move by column.
The point is : **How the column know it's child change size and need to move the other?**

I maked a break point in Column's rebuild，but it does't invoke when click ColorStatefulBox

Answer (score 0):

If you have complex layout decisions that don't exactly fit in the standard workflow, take a look at [Boxy](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy). It takes the layout off "autopilot" and gives you full manual control, solving many issues of layout and sibling sizing.  There are even some convenient widgets to solve many common layout issues, but at any time, you can intercept with "here's a list of children, lemme get their sizes, and I will lay them out for you".

Comment: thanks for your answer, but you did't answer the point: how column knows?

Comment: It's re-rendering the column on every build pass.  Something has to trigger a rebuild for a column to re-lay-out.